# React Native Picker get array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, api, react-native

I am using React Native Picker (official).
In my picker component I need not only the id of specific select record also all the data like name, address etc ...

```
 <Picker
    mode="dropdown"
    headerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#16334c" }}
    headerBackButtonTextStyle={{ color: "#fff" ,marginLeft:-20}}
    headerTitleStyle={{ color:'#fff',alignSelf:'center',marginLeft:50,width:'100%'}}
    textStyle={{color:'#fff',fontSize:12,paddingLeft:8}} 
    style={{height:35,color:'#fff',width:'110%'}}
    selectedValue={this.state.value}
    onValueChange={(itemvalue) =>  this.GetPickerSelectedItemValue(itemvalue)}
    >

        this.props.dropDownType.map((item,i) => {
        return <Item label={item.name} value={item.id} key={i} />
    })}

    </Picker>
```

This is my function `GetPickerSelectedItemValue`:

```
GetPickerSelectedItemValue(itemvalue){
 this.setState({value:itemvalue});
}
```

The problem is that it only gives me the specific id of the select item. I need the array of the item ..

If I change the code like

```
<Item label={item.name} value={item} key={i} />
```

then it give me the array and then on my function I can access all the variables like `item.id`, `item.name`, `item.phone`.

But the main problem is that I have two screens the first one is 'add part' and the second one is 'edit part' on both screens there are two dropdowns (pickers). On addpart screen it's working fine but on editpart there is a problem when the user clicks on edit the dropdown value I sent as a prop which will already selected like

```
  <DropDown
  value={this.state.equipmentLocationID}
  dropDownType={this.state.dataSource.equipment_location}
  left={'88%'}/>
```

there is a value props which I passed and then set the state value to this props like value: `this.props.value` and called this state in `selectedValue` prop of picker but it only works when I add `value={item.id}`, it is not working on `value={item}` means its not showing the selected value on picker by default on edit screen.

I need the whole array of particular id because I need to send other fields of that id on the api that's why I'm doing this...

Any help please???

Comment: Can you please create a demo to show a minimal version of your code? You could use this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0m66mnmnww) as starting point. I would use the `id` in your picker and once you need all data to send to your api just get the relevant object from your array. `value={item}` is not working as the `Picker.Item` component only accepts strings or integers as value and no objects.

Comment: wow your solution works for me :) .. Thanks man , you ' re awesome (y)

Comment: You're welcome. Good to hear that my demo helped.